# How to create AsymmetricGridView with different image sizes in row

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I do lots of google and found many examples and also explore that but ~I want `AsymmetricGridView` different No of images and different images sizes in my grid.

Please find below attached images for my requirement of grid.!

[image]

Please help me for the this type of grid or suggest me library for the this type of asymmetric grid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Arvind...did u get the solution of yours problem...please let me know..because i have also stucked in this problem..thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use following library
https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

[image]

Comment: I tried this but according to my question second and third row is not possible in this library.

Comment: take a look at the screenshot of the library, isn't it the same as your image you posted

Comment: No, Look my first row is identical to this above image but second row has one small and one large image and third row has only one image

Comment: we are giving only idea not full fill your project requirement

Comment: I have set setRequestedColumnCount(3);..If there is one image in the row it shows a green background of the row.I have not set green background anywhere.Why is that and how can i remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [THIS LIBRARY](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) to achieve your goal.Import this lib in your eclipse workspace or include in your gradle if you are using Android Studio

In your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview:library:2.0.1'
}
```

In your layout xml:

```
<com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.widget.AsymmetricGridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In your activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (AsymmetricGridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Choose your own preferred column width
    listView.setRequestedColumnWidth(Utils.dpToPx(this, 120));
    final List<AsymmetricItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // initialize your items array
    adapter = new ListAdapter(this, listView, items);
    AsymmetricGridViewAdapter asymmetricAdapter =
        new AsymmetricGridViewAdapter<>(this, listView, adapter);
    listView.setAdapter(asymmetricAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but according to my question second and third row is not possible in this library.Can you please let me know this thing is possible according to my requirment

Comment: I have seen this library on github and this is exactly what i required but I am not able to follow how to use his library for loading dynamic images.. In my project images are fetched from server.So i am getting url of images from server.I can store them in list but how to implement it with AsymmetricGridView.can u hep me wid this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792625/displaying-dynamic-images-in-asymmetricgridview

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma.if you closely analyse the library and see AsymmetricGridViewAdapter has extended BaseAdapter.So it's like a normal GridView.Just fetch your data,pass it to your adapter and use an image loading library such as Picasso(http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load your item in your image view.

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma well i haven't used this lib in particular.but can you post some image or something to clarify it?

Comment: try with select 2 Column that will show some BLANK cell :(

Comment: I also try this library but it force close app with error after setting adaper.with error -  Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.felipecsl.asymmetricgridview.library.model.AsymmetricItem.getRowSpan()' on a null object reference. Any help please